# How to fix Dash App Exception - Invalid number of output values Expected 2, got 1?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I using `plotly dash app` framework and have callback functions with multiple output values.

When I attempt to deploy the app, it throws an Dash exception. `Invalid number of output values...` I have tried to use `[]` and remove them. However, still noticing the exception.

Here's what App Layout looks like:

```
app.layout = html.Div([

    # header
    html.Div([ 

              dcc.Link(
                 href=app.get_relative_path('/home'),
                 children='Home'
              ),

              dcc.Link(
                 href=app.get_relative_path('/history'),
                 children='History'
              ),

              # For pdf downloads
              dash_extensions.Download(id="download"),
              dcc.Location(id="url"),

              # Page content
              html.Div(id="page-content"),

              # Tab content
              html.Div(id="tab_content"),

      ])
```

Callback

```
# Update page content 

@app.callback([
               Output('page-content', 'children'),
               Output('download', 'data')
              ],
              [Input('url', 'pagename')]
             )
def display_content(page_name):

    # Pages and Links

    if not page_name:
        return [dash.no_update, dash.no_update]

    if page_name == 'history:
        return [history.layout(), dash.no_update]

    else:
        return ['404 Error', dash.no_update]
```

Traceback from the logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
....
_validate.validate_multi_return(output_spec, output_value, callback_id)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dash/_validate.py", line 126, in validate_multi_return
callback_id, len(outputs_list), len(output_value)
172.17.0.19 - - [03/Sep/2020:06:03:32 +0000] "POST /dash-app/_dash-update-component HTTP/1.1" 500 69 "https://example.com/dash-app" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36"

dash.exceptions.InvalidCallbackReturnValue: Invalid number of output values for ..page-content.children...download.data...

Expected the output type to be a list or tuple, but got 1
```

Answer (score 2):

the method `display_content` expects you to return two values. Instead you return a single value, a list.

So instead write:

```
return history.layout(), dash.no_update
```

and

```
return '404 Error', dash.no_update
```

Comment: when I remove the list and return each value as you mentioned, I get `Expected the output type to be a list or tuple but got: None.` exception.

Comment: Hm... . Maybe the children `history.layout()` returns should be a list/tuple but instead it returns `None`?
According to this [link](https://community.plotly.com/t/multiple-outputs-in-dash-now-available/19437) my answer should, on principal, be correct.

Comment: history.layout() seems returns a datatable, that doesn't seem to be the issue. I am trying to return to update tab and page content. I have added more context in the question.